# VC dimension for ellipsoidal classifiers

Tags: approximation-algorithms, machine-learning, lg.learning, vc-dimension

What is the VC dimension of $g: \mathbb{R}^n \times (\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ defined as

$$ g( x, (P_1,p_2,p_3),  ) := \text{sgn} \left( x^\top P_1 x + p_2^\top x + p_3 \right) $$

(where $P_1$ is positive definite)?

Do you think that $(n^2 + 3n)/2$ from [http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4347.pdf] is correct?

In the book [Auger, Doerr. Theory of Randomized Search Heuristics: Foundations and Recent Developments], on pag. 342, I found that $(n^2 + 3n)/2$ is an upper bound.

Comment: This is an "intuitive" answer rather than a rigorous one, but it looks like f and f' are the same function as far as VC dimension is concerned, the role of x is the role alpha took and the role of beta is the role that x took. By this reasoning the VC dimension of the first function is n+1.

Comment: VC dimension is defined for sets, or functions with binary range. if you are thinking of halfspaces, you need to take the sign of the linear form.

Comment: Also, perhaps what you mean is: what is the VC dimension of ranges defined by the set of $f(x,\alpha) \ge 0$ over all $\alpha$ ?

Comment: @ Ross and Suresh: you are right, I meant $\text{sgn}(f)$ or, equivalently the set where $f \geq 0$. Let me point out that the first variable, $x$, is the parameter, while $\alpha$ is the "training" one. In other words, the shattering is done on the space where $\alpha$ lives, and the points/samples taken are like $\alpha^1$, $\alpha^2$, ... Let me try to make this more clear by relabeling the $x$ as $p$, and putting $\alpha$ as first argument.

Comment: Regarding point 2., seems that on the plane the VC dimension is 5 because 6 points cannot be shattered while 5 points can. So I am wondering if in general we have VC dimension less than $n^2+1$

Comment: Pt. 1 seems to be halfspaces, and they are well known to have VC-dim $n+1$ (upper bound by Radon's theorem). Your example I believe is wrong: it's halfspaces through the origin in $n+1$ dimensions, which have VC-dim $n+2$. The upper bound carries over from halfspaces, for the lower bound consider the $n+1$ standard basis vectors and $(-1, \ldots, -1)$.

Comment: Thanks Sasho. I found that bound on a paper. So I guess it is wrong. I'll update the question so. I am now thinking on the quadratic case. Please let me know if you have thoughts about it.

Comment: See Corollary 4.2 in http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387951171

Comment: The analysis suggests that your VC bound should be $(n^2+3n)/2+2$ -- almost what you wrote.